# How to make sure that an object of a class is marshalled automatically by Spring boot if it is a Rest controller

Tags: json, spring, scala, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot app as follows which is responding to the query with a empty JSON "{}" in the body of the response.

according to my understanding the @RestController should autom aticall handle marshling of objects to JSON

Where am I going wrong?

My request :  http://localhost:8080/name/sdhf

The response is :-

**Status :** 200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 353

**Request headers**

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

**Response headers**

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Sun, 22 Feb 2015 21:44:15 GMT

**ResponseBody:**

{}

HelloWebAplication.scala

```
package helloKW
import org.springframework.http.converter.json
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.{RequestMapping, RestController}
/**
 * This object bootstraps Spring Boot web application.
 * Via Gradle: gradle bootRun
 *
 */
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
object HelloWebApplication {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       SpringApplication.run(classOf[AxyzConfig]);
    }
}
```

AxyzConfig.scala

```
package helloKW


import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.{ComponentScan, Configuration}
import org.springframework.http.{HttpStatus, ResponseEntity}
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation._
import org.springframework._

/**
 * This config class will trigger Spring @annotation scanning and auto configure Spring context.
 *
 *     
 */
@RestController
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
class AxyzConfig {
  var m : Moderator = new Moderator(10,"shgd","fsd","ifge")
  var x =10

  @RequestMapping(method = Array {RequestMethod.POST},value=Array{"/name/{name}"})
  @ResponseBody
  def returnParamName(@PathVariable name:String) = new Moderator(45,"sjfg","ksgfs","kurreuk")

}
```

Moderator.scala

```
package helloKW


class Moderator (){
  var id = 10
  var name ="jdgsjdhg"
  var email ="sdkgsd"
  var password ="sdkfjhsdfk"

  def this(a:Int,b:String,c:String,d:String){
    this()
    this.id =  a
    this.email = b
    this.name = c
    this.password = d
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Jackson as your default serializer it is expected a Moderator to be a java bean with getters and setters. As there are no getters and setters the object is empty.

You have two main options.

**Option 1**
Class with [BeanProperty](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.beans.BeanProperty) annotation. I'd prefer a case class here but you're using a regular class which should still be fine. So each field will be something like:

```
@BeanProperty
var name ="jdgsjdhg"
```

**Option 2**
 
Use Case Classes and register Jackson Scala Module with the object mapper. See [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). This to me seems the better option but requires a little extra setup up front.